# Expected Prediction Error for 0-1 Loss Function

Tags: self-study, classification, loss-functions, conditional-expectation

In [ESL](https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print10.pdf) on pages 20 and 21, we have a derivation of expected prediction error of a classification rule $\hat{G}(X)$:

$$
EPE(\hat{G}) = E_X\sum_{k=1}^{K}L[\mathcal{G}_k, \hat{G}(X)]P(\mathcal{G}_k|X)
$$

where $L[k,l]$ is a zero-one loss function, and $\mathcal{G}$ is a set that contains all possible classes.

Then, we find the optimal $\hat{G}$ that minimizes EPE by minimizing prediction loss for each possible input:

$$
\hat{G}(X) = \underset{g \in \mathcal{G}}{\arg\min}\sum_{k=1}^{K}L[\mathcal{G}_k, g]P(G_k|X=x)
$$

Then somehow this can simplify to

$$
\hat{G}(X) = \underset{g \in \mathcal{G}}{\arg\min}(1-P(g|X=x))
$$

How is this simplification derived?

Comment: Exactly one of the $L[\mathcal{G}_k,g]$ equals $1;$ all the other values are zero.

Comment: @whuber isn't it the other way aaround? I thought that only $g=\mathcal{G}_k$ gives a loss function value of $L[\mathcal{G}_k, g=\mathcal{G}_k]= 0$, and all others are penalized with a value of 1.

Comment: I didn't check the reference.  Your definition looks correct and leads to the same result.  My characterization (equal to $1$ minus the loss) makes the result a little more obvious because it immediately reduces the sum to a single term.

Comment: @whuber right but my question was how exactly the reference definition leads to that result?

Comment: Also, in your definition, this would lead to the result being $\hat{G}(x) = \underset{g \in \mathcal{G}}{\arg\min}P(g|X=x)$, which is incorrect, would it not

Comment: Rather than protest, think about it!

Comment: who is protesting?? I'm just trying to understand a derivation...

Comment: The whole point is that use of a 0-1 loss function reduces the sum to something like what's given in the text.  The rest you can work out easily.

Comment: ok sure. Don't really think that protesting comment was necessary. I was trying to contribute insightful responses. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out by writing the sum explicitly: The expected conditional loss given by selecting a class $g$ is given as $\sum P(G_i \neq g|X=x)$, which is effectively equivalent to $1-P(g|X=x)$.